# React-Native Expo Export Web Receiving Error 'Invalid Project Root' While Building Production App

Tags: react-native, build, babeljs

Hi I am receiving the error that the project root is invalid. I will also add that I am using expo alongside my project.

This happens when executing the command ***npx expo export:web***

Also happens when executing the command ***npx expo build***

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

**metro.config.js**
*(Not sure if metro is relevant as I believe it is more for development purposes...)*

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

**react-native.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
    web: {},
  },
  assets: ["./assets/fonts"], // stays the same
};
```

***npm start*** works fine and everything works accordingly in the browser. The goal is to build this for production and begin hosting on a web server.

I am hoping that I am simply missing a location to a directory in a config file but any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, just run it with `expo start`, after it started press `w`.